# Select2 placeholder UI breaking

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-select2

If you see screenshot, When I use placeholder for select2 for multiple select box. It is working fine when I select something from select box, But when I see by default placeholder.

What I am doing: I need to show a placeholder for select2 box,
How to fix this height issue?

```
$('#search_user_events').select2({
            placeholder: 'Select events',
            multiple: true,
            allowClear: true,
            dropdownAutoWidth: true,
            width: '100%'
        });
```

```
<select class="form-control" id="search_user_events" name="search_user_events">
                                                    <option></option>
                                                    @foreach($events as $key => $event)
                                                        <option value="{{$event->id}}">{{$event->name}}</option>
                                                    @endforeach
                                                </select>
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Your issue is up to the first option: empty and selected by default....

You may combine [translateY()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transform-function/translateY) with [.toggleClass( function [, state ] )](https://api.jquery.com/toggleclass/#toggleClass-function-state) and change event:

```js
$('#search_user_events').select2({
    placeholder: 'Select events',
    multiple: true,
    allowClear: true,
    dropdownAutoWidth: true,
    width: '100%'
}).on('change', function (e) {
    $('.select2-search__field').toggleClass('mcenter', $(this).val().length <= 1);
}).trigger('change');
```

```css
.mcenter {
    transform: translateY(-60%);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/select2@4.1.0-beta.1/dist/css/select2.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/select2@4.1.0-beta.1/dist/js/select2.min.js"></script>


<select class="form-control" id="search_user_events" name="search_user_events">
    <option></option>
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
    <option value="3">3</option>
    <option value="4">4</option>
</select>
```